# polymer 3 relative paths

Tags: javascript, svg, polymer, relative-path

I want to migrate a polymer element from polymer 2 to polymer 3.

The polymer element use a relative path to a folder with .svg files.

```
const url = this.resolveUrl('./icons/' + this.icon + '.svg');
```

The problem is that the old component file was a .html file, so if you include it the relative path in the script section is always the same.
Now the component file is a javascript file so the relative path (.) is the path from the file which includes the javascript file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix this, add the following getter method to your element class:

```
static get importMeta() { 
  return import.meta; 
}
```

When your element is loaded, the getter above assigns the `importPath` property of your element. `resolveUrl` will now resolve relative paths based on `importPath` instead of based on the main document.

Incidentally, you can also use `importPath` in data bindings, like this:

```
<img src$="[[importPath]]/icons/[[icon]].png">
```

For more information on why Polymer doesn't rewrite URLs in templates by default, [see the documentation on DOM templating](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/dom-template#urls-in-templates).

(BTW, it looks like the stuff about `importPath` on that page needs an update. I [raised an issue](https://github.com/Polymer/docs/issues/2633) to update the site with the up-to-date info I outlined above.)

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks that worked in polymer.
The only problem is that i can´t parse the module in angular because of the word import

Comment: I'm not sure what your parsing or build process is, but I was able to transpile `import.meta` with polymer-cli and use this with angular. Here's the code: https://github.com/katejeffreys/polymer-angular-demo

Comment: I published the polymer component with nom to our registry and after that i wrote it in the package json in angular as dependecy. If i want to use the component i get
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (21:21)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
    | 
    |     static get importMeta() {
    |         return import.meta;
    |     }
    | 
    i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

Comment: The problem is that wenback is not able to handle import.meta. The issue is already open https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6719

Comment: And for angular (not angular.js) i can´t import the build version of the component. Is there maybe anything i have to change in the build file to say angular to use the build version

Comment: Can you help me to do exactly what you're doing so I can look into it closer? It would be great if you can put an example of your basic use case on github with some instructions for how to reproduce the problem. I will be able to take a better look and post a more detailed answer here if I can reproduce the error myself :)